# Compare 2 List of object's boolean property and return the boolean value true if they matches

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have 2 Objects of type CheckGroupActivity.

phoneActivity and gericaActivity, each has Clients List as property, Client class has one boolean property hasRestrictedClientAccess.

Now I want to compare this 2 list based on this property and return true if all matches.

Tried below solution but it always gives me false(means they are not equal) even if they are.

var restrictedClientAccessIsSame = phoneActivity.Clients?.All(p => gericActivity.Clients.All(g => g.HasRestrictedClientAccess == p.HasRestrictedClientAccess))

Please help.
ex. 
[image]

Comment: Please, don't post code as images and share the minimal reproducible sample

Comment: So you want to check whether `phoneActivity[0].HasRestrictedClientAccess == gericaActivity[0].HasRestrictedClientAccess` AND ``phoneActivity[1].HasRestrictedClientAccess == gericaActivity[1].HasRestrictedClientAccess`, etc? Are those two arrays definitely the same length?

Comment: .All checks that the condition is true for all elements, which is probably not the case.
Use .Where

Comment: @canton7 Yes that's correct. want to check like that. Also they are of same length.

Comment: Are they always guaranteed in the same order? I see the `Client` has an `Id` field, so my assumption is that clients with the same Id need to have the same `HasRestrictedClientAccess` value? If both lists have the same ordering you can use the Zip solution (still risky imo), if not you need to find matches on Id and check those.

Comment: @Knoop Yes your assumption is correct. Both clients array will have same ID and same order. So ordering is not concern here. Just need to check this boolean property for each ID.

I tried 

var restrictedClientAccessIsSame = phoneActivity.Clients.All(p => gericActivity.Clients[phoneActivity.Clients.IndexOf(p)].HasRestrictedClientAccess == p.HasRestrictedClientAccess);

and it seems to be working. It is taking Index into consideration

Answer (score 4):

Provided that the two arrays are the same length, and have the same IDs in the same order, you can use [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) for this:

```
phoneActivity.Clients
   .Zip(gericaActivity.Clients, (x, y) => x.HasRestrictedClientAccess == y.HasRestrictedClientAccess)
   .All(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, taking Index into consideration and its working.

```
var restrictedClientAccessIsSame = phoneActivity.Clients.All(p => gericActivity.Clients[phoneActivity.Clients.IndexOf(p)].HasRestrictedClientAccess == p.HasRestrictedClientAccess);
```

Comment: This is quadratic, and it's easy to get a linear solution (see my answer)